# Flash yocto u-boot to ssd card

Tags: linux, u-boot, solid-state-drive, flash-memory

I've to flash u-boot on a ssd card (dev/mmcblk0) which is partitioned with a fat32 (mmcblk0p1)partition for the u-boot and a ext3 partition(mmcblk0p2) for the linux filesystem.There is a free 1 mb before the first partition and its block size is 512 kb,so i use dd like the following :

```
$ sudo dd if=u-boot.imx of=/dev/mmcblk0p1 bs=512 seek=2 conv=fsync
```

and i got

```
598+0 records in
598+0 records out
306176 bytes (306 kB) copied, 0,0247659 s, 12,4 MB/s
```

but when i mount the partition though xfce i get a weird message:

```
Sorry, could not display all the contents of “4417-3F91”: Error   whengetting information for file '/media/user/4417-3F91/╒Åâª╞â.┌Åâ': Input/output error
```

anyway the partition get mounted and its content obtained by ls is

```
ls
ls: cannot access  áß
                  0¥σ.< /: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ╨ìΓ≡ì╜φ.

                       ä: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ╒Åâª╞â.┌Åâ: Input/output error
ls: cannot access zéâ|éâ.àÉâ: Input/output error
ls: cannot access  æâ@æâ.iæâ: Input/output error
ls: cannot access èvât{â.┤tâ: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ç.á: Input/output error
ls: cannot access <æâqæâ.ZÆâ: Input/output error
ls: cannot access -Æâ)Æâ.íæâ: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ≡à╜φ¿┼â.¼ä: Input/output error
ls: cannot access 0╚ê\ûâ.τê: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ∞╟êwûâ.╚ê: Input/output error
ls: cannot access  /ß≡ê.äûâ: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'ÿâBÿâ.èvâ: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ┘┴ δ╟.0á: Input/output error
ls: cannot access Æ/âΓ éΓ.┴æ: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access táâa≤â.xáâ: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ╢áâ¿áâ.╝Çâ: Input/output error
íâ!íâ.míâ: Input/output error
ls: cannot access zíâéíâ.ÿíâ: Input/output error
ls: cannot access σdåß1âπ. á: Input/output error
ls: cannot access @á/.: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 
ä,aâ.Σ╢à: Input/output error
ls: cannot access súâìúâ.ªúâ: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ┬ñâ▄Ñâ.
Râ: Input/output error
ls: cannot access t{â/Ñâ.añâ: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access d.K/á: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 
               ìσ0áπ.}/á: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ?0áπ.: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ö` α/a: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access αèä. /: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ⁿ0áôª#.&!╙: Input/output error
ls: cannot access Æ▀ìΓ≡ì╜Φ.╟⌐â: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ▐¬â$½â.D½â: Input/output error
ls: cannot access ▒½â╦½â.]¼â: Input/output error
ls: cannot access╨ìΓpç╜φ.α╢à: Input/output error
ls: cannot access (¡â@¡â.U¡â: Input/output error
ls: cannot access }/áπ└ìσ. ì: No such file or directory
>?.,?ƒ  ?.?           #0áπd áπ.? ì  8?ƒσ-?        á0áπ$√ δ.?    ?       áß?0áß.d└É  }/áπ?└ìσ.? ì  èvâ?t{â?.┤tâ  "▐ìΓ≡ü╜Φ.û>á  ö` α/a        táâ?a≤â?.xáâ  ?@-Θ?$éα.h└É  ?≡¥Σ|?ôσ.?  
«?.─    ?.?           ?0áπh0èσ.??Ü  9.⌠           á5ƒσ.?@á      ?   áß?0¥σ.< /   ? áπ╫l.?0ö    ∞╟ê?wûâ?.?╚ê  ?┴îπ?0ìσ.Ç└î  ô? α? ╨σ      t{â?/Ñâ?.añâ  Θ  ???áß.?    ? ╓σ?pçα.?0â
\?      ?.?           ⁿ0áπô??α.??è  ?9ûσ?PEΓ      A.? á         ??áß.? á        
.....
```

what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you wrote to **mmcblk0p1** which is the first partition of mmcblk0 insted of **mmcblk0** itself.